# Inject a JavaScript code in Webview iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I created a iOS web browser with swift language code. And add an extra button to inject a script on that web page, but it always crash when I try this:

```
webView!.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.background = 'red';", nil)
```

Any idea how to fix this? And how to read the JavaScript code from a file, and then inject it to that webview element.

I use the code style as this example but with *WKWebView*:
 https://github.com/rshankras/WebViewDemo

**If you can solve this question I need a basic working code in the answer. And solution for how to load the JavaScript from a file. And inject that code in the WKWebView element.**

Comment: Can you provide some information about the crash you have ?

Comment: "Thread 1:signal SIGABRT"

Comment: Are you using `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` ?

Comment: I have converted that sample in github to WKWebView. I use WKWebView

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the method you are using (evaluateJavaScript) in the current [UIWebView API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/) but it is in the [WKWebView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:).  Maybe you are using the wrong API?  Perhaps try using  [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) instead:

```
let script = "document.body.style.background = 'red'"
if let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(script) {
    println("result is \(result)")
}
```

Also, i'm not sure if the "!" is needed (a hunch tells me it's not), as there is no context around your code.  So maybe try both versions.

Getting a string from a file is something like:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsFileName", ofType: "js")
if let content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
    println("js content is \(content)")
}
```

Loading from disk has a lot of variables around how your file is being copied and stored so your going to have to do some work to fit the `path` variable to your structure.

Comment: Still error, can you provide me a basic code sample

Comment: I use WKWebview, and give me this error: 'WKWebView' does not have a member named 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString'

Comment: what about if you try your original code but like `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.background = 'red';", completionHandler:nil)`, like with no "!" ?  are you able to call any method on that webView without issue?

Answer (score 2):

This will work with WKWebView. Dont forget to add WebKit frame work on top on your class definition

```
      var webView: WKWebView!

 func loadWebViewWithCustomJavaScript {
    //Create Preferences 
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    //Initialise javascript file with user content controller and configuration
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let scriptURL =    NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Your File Name", ofType: "js")
    var scriptContent = ""
    do {
        scriptContent = try String(contentsOfFile: scriptURL!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch{
    print("Cannot Load File")
   }
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent, injectionTime: .AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    configuration.preferences = preferences
    //Create WebView instance
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height), configuration: configuration)
    view.addSubview(webView)
    //Finally load the url
    let url = NSURL(string:"your URL")
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
  }
```

Sample JavaScript code for injection

```
 //Hides name of "background1" element on the page
 var styleTag = document.createElement("style");
 styleTag.textContent = 'div#background1, .after-post.widget-area      {display:none;}';
document.documentElement.appendChild(styleTag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using following. Used String instead of NSString to use native swift 2. Javascript code to inject must be in hidesections.js file

```
    let jsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hidesections", ofType: "js");
    let jsContent: String?
    do
    {
        jsContent = try String(contentsOfFile: jsPath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch _
    {
        jsContent = nil
    }
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsContent!)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WKWebView` here is a solution.

```
if let scriptFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("script", ofType: "js") {
    var error: NSError?
    let scriptString = NSString(contentsOfFile: scriptFile, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
    if let error = error {
        println("Error: Could not load script file => \(error)")
    } else {
        if let scriptString = scriptString {
            let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptString, injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
            let controller = WKUserContentController()
            controller.addUserScript(script)

            let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            configuration.userContentController = controller

            let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
            self.webView = webView
            self.view.addSubview(webView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I click on the button (with this code). Everything is gone, I see no web view element, only a white page with a long scroll bar.

Comment: still nothing visible here.