# How to send array from native IOS to javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I'm working on an app sending data from JS to native ios controller. By what method can i send an array from IOS controller to Javascript file.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject a JavaScript code in Webview iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573528/inject-a-javascript-code-in-webview-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this [article on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/).

In brief, you should use WKWebView and look into **Injecting Behavior with User Scripts**.

Code from article:

```
let source = "document.body.style.background = \"#777\";"
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController = userContentController
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
```

Be more specific next time asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call you JS function with array as parameter:

```
NSArray *a = @[@"foo", @"bar", @"baz"];
NSMutableArray *q = [NSMutableArray array];
// Add quotes to strings
for (NSString *s in a) {
    [q addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", s]];
}
NSString *f = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"youJSFunction([%@]);", [q componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:f]; // UIWebView
```

This will call in JS `myJSFunction(["foo","bar","baz"]);`