# How can I inject js to wkwebview from sandbox?

Tags: javascript, wkwebview, inject

How can I inject js to wkwebview from sandbox?
I try to use `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/91F28FB0-A67A-403A-BA93-3BCD65FEBE5D/tmp/www/plugin.js`,but it does not work.

I want to inject js file to wkwebview,the file I get from the server. I do not know what to do now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject a JavaScript code in Webview iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573528/inject-a-javascript-code-in-webview-ios)

Comment: My js file is in the sandbox,bot mainBundle. I can not inject it successfully