# Inject Javascript into Webview - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, webview

How can I inject javascript into a webview (IOS/Swift) after loading some custom html.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var html = "<div id='test'></div>"

self.webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

I want to inject the following javascript into the webview after I load my custom html.

```
var myelement = document.getElementById("test");
myelement.innerHTML= "New Text";
```

Comment: evaluate JavaScript, google that, it is hard to be easier to find

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject a JavaScript code in Webview iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573528/inject-a-javascript-code-in-webview-ios)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just do:

```
let js = "var myelement = document.getElementById(\"test\");myelement.innerHTML= \"New Text\";"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
```

If you are using `UIWebView` instead of `WKWebView`, do this:

```
let js = "var myelement = document.getElementById(\"test\");myelement.innerHTML= \"New Text\";"
_ = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: js)
```

Answer (score 6):

use WKWebview  and use   `WKNavigationDelegate` Delegate

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let str = "setData(\"\(uid)\",\"\(DataProvider.sharedInstance.baseUrl)\")"
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(str) { (id, error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still there, just Swift 4-ized / modularized; try this signature: `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`. (Injecting the JS here does the job for me -- thanks!)