# ios - how to open a swift view using javascript in a web view?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview

In my app, I have a webview, and I would like to have a button that will open another view in Swift. Is there a way to use have that button in the webview itself and use javascript to have it segue to the next view? If so, how can I implement this?

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573528/inject-a-javascript-code-in-webview-ios OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996624/inject-javascript-into-webview-swift

Comment: Both of those involve using javascript in WebViews, but I'm not sure how they relate to my specific question. Thank you for the information, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use **webViewJavaScript bridge** classes and use it functions and web view delegate methods for interacting.

**objective C link** https://github.com/lokimeyburg/WebViewJavascriptBridge 
for swift use it by simply importing `#import "WebViewJavascriptBridge.h"` in your `AppName-bridging-header.h`

Comment: Thank you! I've never created anything with bridges, though, so I'm not 100% sure how to implement this. Do you have any tips/links to good guides?