# Show keyboard on button click by calling WKWebview input field

Tags: javascript, iphone, swift

I have been searching a lot about this question I have and without any luck, how do I make keyboard on iphone to show by clicking a button, and set the focus on the WKWebview input field?

I have this code which initialize a button and calls a func in swift 3

```
let keyBoardButton = UIButton (type: .custom)
    keyBoardButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "keyboard.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    keyBoardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showKeyboard), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    keyBoardButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
```

and i am calling this func

```
    func showKeyboard() {

    self.delay { [weak self] in
        let javascript = " document.getElementById('myID').focus();"

        self?.webView?.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { [weak self] (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else if let result = result{
                print(result)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am setting the focus on my input field, but i do not know how to show the keyboard, anyone who can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the `evaluateJavaScript` method on `WKWebView` to run some javascript on the page that focuses the textfield.

The javascript will depend on the page, but it could be something like this.

```
let js = "document.getElementById(\"MY_TEXTFIELD_ID\").focus();"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(js)
```

---

Edit: After some more digging, it appears that this is a known bug in WebKit.
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142757

Comment: I have tried that, but thats not enough to show the keyboard.

Comment: do you know how to bring up the keyboard? because this only sets the focus.

Comment: I updated my post, it appears that this is a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue

after using this 
[Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34674372/6508602) to inject Javascript into your WebKitView, simply used

```
document.getElementById('myID').focus();
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myClass').focus();
```

to add the focus() attribute to your input